# Function chaining in c# using extension methods on delegates. Is there any performance implications. I am posting code snippet with usage

Tags: c#, functional-programming, delegates, method-chaining

Extension on Delegate. Suggestion and any improvements are welcomed. This code is being currently used in the one of the projects.

```
internal static class xt
{
    public static Func<From, To> Next<From, To>(this From @obj, Func<From, To> transform)
    {
        return (fr) => transform(fr);
    }

    public static Func<Tform, TForward> Next<Tform, Tto, TForward>(this Func<Tform, Tto> g, Func<Tto, TForward> f)
    {
        return (tf) => f(g(tf));
    }

    public static Tto Input<Tfrom, Tto>(this Func<Tfrom, Tto> fx, Tfrom data)
    {
        return fx(data);
    }

    public static void Execute(this Action fx)
    {
        fx();
    }

    public static Func<Tform, Tto> Next<Tform, Tto>(this Func<Tform> g, Func<Tform, Tto> f)
    {
        return tf => f(g());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: I believe this is better placed at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only performance implications you face is the memory allocation for delegates.  However, these are small and short-lived, will live in Gen0 and be collected in a quick operation.

I don't think you should be concerned about it.  There are usually way more performance-threatening elements in the code you should be concerned about - string processing, array processing, etc.

Comment: I got it. I want to handle if else branches with this method. Any suggestion(s)?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://davefancher.com/2015/06/14/functional-c-fluent-interfaces-and-functional-method-chaining/).